# how to create a dictionary out of a join from sqlalchemy to python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am using `python` and `SQLAlchemy`

After joining two tables and used a `_asdict()` to create an array of dictionary out of the result, i am facing the data below and trying to find a good way to create a single dictionary out of it.

## data from query

```
data = [{'User': <app.data_access.models.User object at 0x7fcb, 'Products': <app.data_access.models.Availability object at 0x7fcb>}
{'User': <app.data_access.models.User object at 0x7fcb>, 'Products': <app.data_access.models.Products object at 0x7fcb>}]
```

The object `User` table has the same data for the two instances with the fields: `first_name`, "last_name" only but `Products` instances are have different in terms of data.

Below is the data structure that i am trying to create as a result:

## result expected

```
dic = {
  "first_name": "xyz",
  "last_name": "zba"
  "products": [{"all the fields of Products instance 1"}, {"all the fields of Products instance 2"}
}
```

I am running out of ideas, everything I tried have failed.

## example:

```
result = {}

for data in some_query:
  for key, value in data.items():
     if key == "Products":
        response["products"] = [value]
     elif key == "User":
        response.update(value)

print(result)
```

How can i possibly create dictionary as a result using python from the query above?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you share the query you're currently working with? Sharing the model classes might be helpful too.

Comment: @YaakovBressler the guy from the python meetup online lol

Comment: That's me! It's been a hot minute.